# Creating TypeScript enum with display value

Tags: enums, typescript

I have a typescript enum that looks like this:

```
enum State {
    NotRequired,
    Working,
    PendingReview,
    Reviewed,
    Done
}
```

And this generates this:

```
var State;
(function (State) {
    State[State["NotRequired"] = 0] = "NotRequired";
    State[State["Working"] = 1] = "Working";
    State[State["PendingReview"] = 2] = "PendingReview";
    State[State["Reviewed"] = 3] = "Reviewed";
    State[State["Done"] = 4] = "Done";
})(State || (State = {}));
```

I would like to have the values a nicely formed string with spaces where required.

So `State[State["PendingReview"] = 2] = "PendingReview";` would become `State[State["PendingReview"] = 2] = "Pending Review";`

I have managed to achieve something close to this by defining my enum like so:

```
enum State {
    "Not Required",
    Working,
    "Pending Review",
    Reviewed,
    Done
}
```

However this has the drawback that to use any enum value in code with a space i now have to use my key instead.

So `State.PendingReview` now has to be used like this `State["Pending Review"]`

Can i have the best of both worlds by somehow defining an alternative display string to my key?

So that when i say `State[State.PendingReview]` it gives me the value `"Pending Review"`

Answer (score 4):

As you're not specifying explicit values for the enum, you may as well use a string enum (available as of TypeScript 2.4) for this:

```
enum State {
  NotRequired = "Not Required",
  Working = "Working",
  PendingReview = "Pending Review",
  Reviewed = "Reviewed",
  Done = "Done"
}
```

The display value then simply becomes e.g. `State.NotRequired`.

Answer (score 1):

Since enums does not supports string values, 
would be better to use a class with static fields like this.

You have the compilation checks like if you where using enum, you call it the same way in your code also.

```
module rizze.tests {


enum State{
     NotRequiered,
     Working,
     Pending,
     Reviewed,
     Done
}

class StateConvert {
    static NotRequiered="Not Required";
    static Working="I'm Working";
    static Pending = "Pending Review";
    static Reviewed="Reviewed Done";
    static Done="Done All";

    static convert(state:State):String{
        if( state == null) return null;
        switch(state){
            case State.NotRequiered:{return StateConvert.NotRequiered;}
            case State.Working:{return StateConvert.Working;}
            case State.Pending:{return StateConvert.Pending;}
            case State.Reviewed:{return StateConvert.Reviewed;}
            case State.Done:{return StateConvert.Done;}

        }
          console.log("Error state  undefined + " +state );
          return null;  

    }
}





 export class StateTest {

      constructor(){
         let state:State = State.Reviewed;
         console.log("state:"+state + " / " + StateConvert.convert(state));   

      }

  }

//TEST
let s:StateTest= new StateTest();
```

}

Comment: I also still want them to be enums as in `State.PendingReview == 2` but `State[State.PendingReview] == "Pending Review"`

Comment: you will have to code it manually. Because this is using 2 principles that are completely different and imcompatible (due to typescript langage design)

Answer (score 0):

> Can i have the best of both worlds by somehow defining an alternative
>   display string to my key?

No. This is not supported in TypeScript. You could try to make a [feature request](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues) if you think this would be valuable.